# UIActivityIndicatorView not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to implement a UIActivityIndicatorView that runs while the user is in the middle of an in app purchase. For some reason the UIActivityIndicatorView is not showing up even though I have made if a subview of the view.

```
class RemoveAdsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func btnAdRemoval(sender: UIButton) {
    let buyProgress = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
    buyProgress.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(buyProgress)
    buyProgress.startAnimating()
    print(buyProgress)
    PFPurchase.buyProduct("", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
    buyProgress.stopAnimating()
    buyProgress.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

PFRestore:

```
restoreProgress.startAnimating()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
       PFPurchase.restore()
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           restoreProgress.stopAnimating()
       })
 })
```

Comment: See all of the Related questions shown to the right --> You should check those. This issue has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @rmaddy I've checked them already and the answers did not solve my problem which is why I posted my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking another look, the problem is simple. You stop and remove the activity indicator much too soon. You need to stop and remove it in the completion block.

```
@IBAction func btnAdRemoval(sender: UIButton) {
    let buyProgress = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
    buyProgress.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(buyProgress)
    buyProgress.startAnimating()
    print(buyProgress)
    PFPurchase.buyProduct("", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
        buyProgress.stopAnimating()
        buyProgress.removeFromSuperview()

        if error != nil{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

You also need to make sure that the contents of the completion block is being done on the main thread.

Comment: This does get the activity indicator to show up, but after the transaction is completed the UIActivityIndicatorView remains spinning, because there's no error

Comment: I put it in the wrong place, my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I attempted to so something similar for PFPurchase using the link you had showed me initially but I still run into the same problem. Could you take a look? I updated the OP.

Comment: Looks like `PFPurchase.restore()` returns immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do this

```
buyProgress.startAnimating()
```

followed by this immediatly

```
buyProgress.stopAnimating()
```

because  PFPurchase.buyProduct is an async call it will return immediately and your not seeing your activity indicator animate as its all happening in one run loop cycle.

you need to move

```
buyProgress.stopAnimating()
```

inside the closure like so

```
PFPurchase.buyProduct("", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                buyProgress.stopAnimating()

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
```